# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method (Trying to get Previous and Next record)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to get the Previous and Next Record, but I am getting an exception at run time. What am I doing wrong? I found this solution to my problem on the internet. I get the basic idea, but I am not very experienced with LINQ.

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[CXW__DAQ___Web.Models.Report] SkipWhile[Report(System.Linq.IQueryable`1[CXW_*DAQ***Web.Models.Report],System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[CXW__DAQ**_Web.Models.Report,System.Boolean]])' method, and  his method cannot be translated into a store expression.

here is my relevant code.

```
        var NextRecord = db.Reports.OrderBy(i => i.ID)
                    .SkipWhile(i => i.ID != id)
                    .Skip(1)
                    .First();
        int nextID = NextRecord.ID;

        var PrevRecord = db.Reports.OrderBy(i => i.ID)
                .Reverse()
                .SkipWhile(i => i.ID != id)
                .Skip(1)
                .Last();
        int prevID = PrevRecord.ID;
```

Comment: Did you try compiling just NextRecord? I.o.w. did you get 1 or 2 errors?

Comment: I got one error at run time. It never got to to the PrevRecord Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the error message is trying to tell you is that LINQ to Entities has no way to translate the `IEnumerable.SkipWhile()` method into SQL. You'll first have to force the remainder of the query to use LINQ to Objects first instead:

```
var nextRecord = 
    db.Reports.OrderBy(i => i.ID)
              .AsEnumerable()
              .SkipWhile(i => i.ID != id)
              .Skip(1)
              .First();
```

The obvious downside here being that your entire table is going to be ordered and then read into memory.

Comment: So _why_ exactly does `SkipWhile(IQueryable<T> src, ...)` fail here? That's not obvious.

Comment: That Did solve my problem. Will mark answered when the timer is up.

However is there a "better" method then? That isn't so memory hungry?

Comment: The sheer existence of `Queryable.SkipWhile()` suggests that there are possibilities. But maybe with `i.ID < id` or something. Why do you think it is `IEnumerable.SkipWhile()` ?

Comment: @TheColonel26 the best method would be to run 2 queries separately, one like the following example: `select top 1 * ... where ID < ID order by ID desc` and then another one like: `select top 1 * ... where ID > ID order by ID ASC`. That way, you let the database do all the job for you and uses as small memory as you can possibly hope for. I leave you the translation to LINQ as exercise.

Comment: @HenkHolterman If you were going to do it that way, it might as well be part of where, and it woulnd't be doing the same thing that `SkipWhile` does, because the data wouldn't be included in the query in the first place. Anyway, I didn't make the design decision...but I can see why it was omitted.

Comment: @Icarus but by doing select top 1 wouldn't I only be pulling one record? and wouldn't that record be my current record? where as I need either the one before it or the one after it instead?

Comment: @TheColonel26 It looks like you know the ID of the current record (at least I see an `id` parameter in your 2 queries). What I suggest you do is that you use that ID to retrieve from the database the previous and the next record only. And yes, `select top 1` will only return one record at a time but is far more efficient that Justin's solution. If the database has an index on the ID column, it's likely going to use that index to find the exact 2 records you are looking for in the most efficient way possible (index seek). Justin's solution is a good one only on tiny tables.

Comment: @Icarus OOOO ok I get it now. I missed this where ID < id and where ID > id. I get the concept. Now I just have to figure out how to do it with linq. Thanks

Comment: @TheColonel26 The LINQ version should be something like: `var next = db.Reports.Where(x=>x.ID>id).OrderBy(x=>x.ID).First();` and `var previous = db.Reports.Where(x=>x.ID<id).OrderByDescending(x=>x.ID).First();` where `id ` is whatever the id of the current record is.

Comment: @Icarus Thanks, I should have reported back sooner. It took me about 20 minutes of playing around with it but yeah that is exactly what I ended up with.